# Google Analytics API requests quota

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a problem with my project Analytics API into Google Developer Console.

Every day, when daily quotas are refreshed (at midnight Pacific time), my project calls a lot of requests so i must disable and then enable again analytics API.

In this way, quota stops and Google will not show me the error "Quota Error: profileId ga:xxxxxx has exceeded the daily request limit." when reach quota of 10,000 requests per view (profile) per day.

None of my projects called requests at midnight Pacific time so I don't understand because of this increase of quota.

Comment: You can only make 10000 requests a day to the core reporting api for each view.   It resets at midnight Pacific time.  Something you are doing though out the day is making a lot of requests to the api.  Turning on and off the API to over ride the limit really isn't a good idea stop making so many requests.

Comment: Also the quota you mention is per view (profile) not project. Even if your project is not making API calls as soon as that view (profile) reaches 10k requests in a day you will receive the error.

Answer (score 0):

What methods are you calling? Write methods (e.g. insert) are more strict 500 per day.
There's also a limit of concurrent 10 calls per second.